# Trying to understand Walrasian equilibrium (Brown & Matzkin 1996)

Tags: pure-exchange-economy

I'm trying to understand page 6-7 of the [Brown & Matzkin paper](http://www.econ.ucla.edu/rmatzkin/research/Brown_Matzkin.pdf). Here is an example:

Consider a 2-person, 2-good pure exchange economy $E=(u_i,w_i)_{i=1}^2$ where both utility functions are continuous, strictly quasi-concave and strictly monotone. The endowments are $w_1=(0,5)$ and $w_2=(2,1)$. Let $\bar{E}=(u_i,\bar{w}_i)_{i=1}^2$ be another exchange economy, with endowments $\bar{w}_1=(5,0)$ and $\bar{w}_2=(1,2)$.

Now I want to show that if $p=(5,6)$ is a Walrasian equilibrium price vector for economy $E$, then $\bar{p}=(6,5)$ cannot be a Walrasian equilibrium price vector for $\bar{E}$. The paper mentions using Afriat's theorem, but I'm having a difficult time finding the correct path to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider consumer 1. Let $(x,y)$ be his optimal consumption bundle in the first equilibrium and let $(\bar x, \bar y)$ be his optimal consumption bundle in the second equilibrium.

Then the budget restriction in the first equilibrium gives:
$$
30 = 5 x + 6 y \leftrightarrow y = 5 - \frac{5}{6} x
$$
The restrictions on the total endowment gives:
$$
x \le 2.
$$
From this, it follows that:
$$
\begin{align*}
6 x + 5 y &= 6 x + 5 \left(5 - \frac{5}{6} x\right),\\
&=6 x + 25 - \frac{25}{6} x,\\
&=\frac{11}{6} x + 25 \le \frac{22}{6} + 25,\\
&< 30.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, the total income for individual 1 in the second equilibrium is $30 (= 6 \times 5)$. With this money, he could have bought the bundle that he consumed in the first period, because:
$$
6 x + 5 y < 30.
$$
By a simple revealed preference argument, this means that consumer 1 prefers the chosen bundle $(\bar x, \bar y)$ over the bundle $(x,y)$. (He consumed the bundle $(\bar x, \bar y)$ but the bundle $(x,y)$ was cheaper to obtain.)

Now, we we do a similar exercise for the second equilibrium. The budget constraint in the second equilibrium gives:
$$
30 = 6 \bar x + 5 \bar y \leftrightarrow \bar x = 5 - \frac{5}{6} \bar y.
$$
Also, the endowment constraint gives:
$$
\bar y \le 2.
$$
As such,
$$
\begin{align*}
5 \bar x + 6 \bar y &= 5\left(5 - \frac{5}{6} \bar y\right) + 6 \bar y,\\
&= 25 - \frac{25}{6} \bar y + 6 \bar y,\\
&= 25 + \frac{11}{6} \bar y \le 25 + \frac{22}{6},\\
&< 30
\end{align*}
$$
The income for individual 1 in the first equilibrium is $30 = (6 \times 5)$. With this money, he could have bought the bundle in the second equilibrium because:
$$
5 \bar x + 6 \bar y < 30,
$$
which means that the bundle $(x,y)$ which he actually purchased is preferred over the bundle $(\bar x, \bar y)$.

To conclude, our consumer prefers $(x,y)$ over $(\bar x, \bar y)$ and he prefers $(\bar x, \bar y)$ over $(x,y)$, which is a contradiction.